# Caching Images?

Tags: android, network-programming

I am developing a Food Recommendation Engine. We have a lot of photos which has to be downloaded from the server during the usage of the Application.

Do we need to cache or store the images locally just to reduce the network activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data from the server is not going to change then you should store them but if the data is changed then you can do two things

1. On the server keep a last updated data date and depending on that always fetch that date from server, check if the last updated data is not obsolete if yes then fetch again or there is no need
2. Second approach is Store as cache and fetch every time you start your app

Comment: lets say on an activity i have 15 images.. but when the second time the Activity is loaded - 5 new images have changed. What do u do in this situation ? so we have 10 images from the previous list and 5 that have to be newly downloaded.

Comment: You mean to say not all the images only few of the images are changed, if thats the case its totally depend upon the situation if you have 100 of images and only 10 are changed then create a web service that will also tell you about the updated images in conjunction with date and you can write simple AI(logic) on what situation what best suits you

Comment: ok. What are the factors i need to consider when doing a local Cache dump on a mobile ? Can i do it on the SD card.. and upto what MB is it ok to utilize so that the app doesn't eat out all the memory :P

Comment: Its general for cache its better to use /data/data/packagename/ but if the data is small otherwise in general for heavy data always use  sdcard and delete the folder when you exit your app

Comment: Oh you suggest to delete the data on exiting the app ? is it bad to have say 1-2mb of cache until the app is uninstalled ? like how the nokia maps does on the Nokia Phones ?

Comment: I suggested that in caching and reason for that is, look in days of nokia there are not so much apps out there but in case of Android there are tons of app in market and if every app store data on sdcard like this user must be frowned upon its sdcard usage and the amounts of folder created on sdcard if the data is really small as in your case 1 or 2MB then you can hide the folder by appending a dot in name folder that will make it hidden, also during uninstall you were not we able to remove that folder

Comment: Do u knw any resource where i can learn or see any such caching implementation ? Thanks for your time. Really helping me make the decision :)

Comment: Nope right now its a big idea depending on your situation and I dont have any link right know, but you can always start from achieving few things at intial and later concentarting on whole of the concept of caching, and feel free to ask questions

Comment: Why not give user a choice to decide if he/she wants to use image caching and if yes - then how much space to spare for it? Use sensible defaults in case user does not care about it.